# Ошибка при преобразовании строки в массив jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post">
   <p><textarea id=f13 name="field1"></textarea></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>

<div id="content">111</div>
<div id="result">555</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myForm').submit(function(){

var str = $(this).serialize();
var str2 = $('#f13').val();
str2.split('\n');  

srt2.forEach(function(item, i, srt2) { $('.result').html(item); });

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: str,
                success:
                function(html){
         $("#content").html(html);
               }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

И тут ошибка...
Необходимо, чтобы произошло создание массива, разделителем при котором будет новая строка, а далее выведен результат по очереди.

Comment: Просто `str2.split('\n');`

Comment: Видимо я криворукий и слепой, но так у меня и не заработало....

Comment: @Dvashington строку `var str3 = str2.split('\n'); ` заменить на `str2.split('\n'); `

Comment: Логика приведённого вами кода загадочна. В частности конструкция `srt3.forEach(function(item, i, srt3) { $('#result').html(str3); });`. Зачем для каждого элемента массива выводите в #result весь массив?

Comment: Там вместо str3 нужно item - опечатка

Comment: Принципиально ничего не изменится, содержимоей #result будет перезаписано столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве.Объясните, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: Ввожу значения: Маша Даша Саша Дима. У меня создается несколько div:      <div class="result">Маша</div>      <div class="result">Даша</div> и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var result = $('#result');
$('#f13').keypress(function(e) { //Будем реагировать на ввод новой строки
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var items = text.split('\n').map(function(item) { //Создаём массив, содержащий div для каждого строки
            return $('<div class="result">' + item + '</div>');
        });
        result.html(items); //Заменяем содержимое #result
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="f13"></textarea>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: У меня все попроще. После нажатия на submit появляются дивы)

Comment: Нет проблем, используйте событие `submit`. Мой код - только пример, чтобы вы поняли принцип.

Comment: Так и сделаю. В оригинале я потом каждое из значений буду скармливать пхп файлу и выдавать с него результат.

Comment: Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, отметьте его решением.

Comment: Переписал под себя, все получилось. Отмечаю